# how to save current game in chessboard.js

Tags: javascript, chess, chessboard.js

I am using [chessboard.js](http://chessboardjs.com/) script.

But I am facing a problem. I want to save a current game without end, save the current position and next time to use saved current position.

```
var cfg = { 
        position: 'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R'
    };
var board = new ChessBoard('board', cfg);
```

Current position is showed correctly. But when I move, it goes to "start" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>For storing in browser you could use [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) or [localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490869/reading-and-writing-from-localstorage).</del>

<del>Alternatively, you could send state to server and later read it using AJAX.</del>

**EDIT:**

Looks like you have mistake in script. Instead of

```
new ChessBoard('board', cfg);
```

you should do

```
new ChessBoard('board', cfg.position);
```

Docs: http://chessboardjs.com/examples#1003

Comment: I do not think that's what is being asked by the OP.

Comment: Thank for your answer.But I save the current position to database.Later I will use that position .It take may be 20 days later.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the state of the board using

```
var saved_positions =  ChessBoard.objToFen(board.position())
```

...or  if you're using the chess.js library for managing the game you can simply  use

```
var saved_positions = game.fen()
```

both will return a string containing the position of every piece on the board.

Then to load the saved board position with animations you can use:

```
 board.position(saved_position, true);
```

or  to instantly set the positions

```
 board.position(saved_position, false);
```

Enjoy.